# tkinter button command: RuntimeError: threads can only be started once

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I got a "RuntimeError: threads can only be started once" while coding my app in tkinter and I would like to get rid of it. After clicking the button I need to run my function in a thread in order to avoid window freeze because the executed function takes time to complete. Problem is that I want to be able to click the button again and again. Here is my button code:

self.release_ip_button = Button(self.test_frame, text='Release Address', height=2, width=12,
command=threading.Thread(target=controller.release_ip,
name='release_thread').start)

This button then executes the function release_ip() inside my controller. There are situations when I want to repeat this action. But since a thread object can be started only once I got an error.

Any ideas how to avoid it? I tried already giving different names to the threads but it did not help.

Many thanks

Comment: It should be `command=lambda: threading.Thread(...).start()`.

Answer (score 0):

[acw1668](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5317403/acw1668) said [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72898678/tkinter-button-command-runtimeerror-threads-can-only-be-started-once/72915177#comment128758108_72898678):

> It should be `command=lambda: threading.Thread(...).start()`.

which provided the solution.